# Immutable value only has mutating members

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift

I've declared an array using `var` and filled it within an `init()`. Yet, when I try to mutate that array I get heaps of errors telling my the array is immutable. What am I missing here?

```
struct Deck {
    var cards: Card[] = []

    init () {
        for i in 1...4 {
            for ii in 1...13 {
                self.cards.append(Card(rank: Rank.fromRaw(ii)!, suit: Suit.fromRaw(i)!))
            }
        }
    }

    func shuffle () {
        var shuffledDeck: Card[] = []
        var count = self.cards.count

        for i in 1...52 {
            var limit = count - i
            var key = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(limit)));
            shuffledDeck.append(self.cards[key])
            self.cards.removeAtIndex(key)
        }

        self.cards = shuffledDeck
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting:

```
Playground execution failed: error:
<REPL>:75:22: error: immutable value of type 'Card[]' only has mutating members named 'removeAtIndex'
            self.cards.removeAtIndex(key)
                 ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<REPL>:78:24: error: cannot assign to 'cards' in 'self'
            self.cards = shuffledDeck
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `struct` is considered a value type, so it’s immutable by default. If you want to change it using a method, you have to declare the method `mutating`. Quoting the Swift book:

> Structures and enumerations are value types. By default, the
>   properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance
>   methods.
>
> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or
>   enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating
>   behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change)
>   its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes
>   are written back to the original structure when the method ends. The
>   method can also assign a completely new instance to its implicit self
>   property, and this new instance will replace the existing one when the
>   method ends.
>
> You can opt in to this behavior by placing the `mutating` keyword before
>   the `func` keyword for that method.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That did it.

I had to change `let deck = Deck()` into `var deck = Deck()` to make it work, though.

Comment: That's because with `let deck = Deck()` you defined your `Deck` to be immutable, and you're trying to mutate it with your function shuffle. I'm wondering if changing your struct to a class would be a better approach if you want to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: Using a class is definitely a better approach for this idea.